# Obtain a GridRow field by clicking a button on same row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridRow that looks like the following:

```
item_id  name  age
1        bob   13     (button)
2        tom   4      (button)
5        jim   24     (button)
```

In my grid view the button was added like so:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_id" HeaderText="item_id" 
        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression=item_id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" 
        SortExpression="name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="age" HeaderText="age" 
        SortExpression="age" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterClick" DataField="button" HeaderText="button" SortExpression="button"
          CommandName="button" 
          CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
          Text="Register" />
      </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

How can I get the item_id value by simply clicking on the button in the row?
I would like to access the item_id value in the OnClick method.  Any ideas how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

In the CommandArgument of text box, bind the item_id instead of the row index. That's probably the fastest.

```
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterClick" DataField="button" HeaderText="button" SortExpression="button"
          CommandName="button" 
          CommandArgument='<%# Eval("item_id") %>'
          Text="Register" />
```

In the button click event,

```
protected void RegisterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var itemId = (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other comment mentioned, bind the "item_id" instead of using the row index. Instead of:

```
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
```

Try (use single quotations instead of double):

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("item_id") %>'
```

In the code behind use the following to get the id:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
```